# Can I use nfs on 2 VMs connected on a host-only network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vmware, nfs

I have a windows 10 host running VMWare Workstation 12. I have an Ubuntu Server guest and an Xubuntu Desktop guest.

The Ubuntu Server has nfs server setup on it. On the Xubuntu Desktop I have setup my fstab to mount a few folders from the server.

I usually have the Windows host connected to my network over ethernet, and use Bridged networking. Then have my router assign IPs to the VMs.

This setup works well, but this week I am travelling so I need to switch the VMs over to a host only network. When I do this they can see each other and I can ssh from the Xubuntu Desktop to the Ubuntu Server. But the nfs wont mount.

```
$ sudo mount -a
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.186.128:/vol/
```

I ran this to search the log files on both VMs

```
grep -rl "nfs" /var/log
```

and don't see anything relevant, so now I'm not sure what to do next.

edit:

This is the relevant line in /etc/fstab on the desktop vm

```
192.168.186.128:/vol/   /vol/  nfs  rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr  0 0
```

and this is the relevant line from /etc/exports on the server vm

```
/vol/   192.168.0.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the ssh connection takes a lot longer to open than it did with the bridged network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably OT here.

but `192.168.0.0/24` does not include `192.168.186.128`  either change the exports to be `192.168.186.0/24`  or `192.168.0.0/16`  as both of those will include `192.168.186.128`

the reason ssh it taking longer is probably due to the host lookup ssh is performing timing out due to lack of DNS resolution.  You can try adding server's ip to /etc/hosts on the desktop and vice versa,  might help a bit.

Comment: The change in the exports worked, thanks. I'm not too worried about the slow connection time with ssh, but I don't think it's dns as I have my ssh config file setup with the ip address for the Host.

Comment: the delay is sshd  looking up the connecting IP address which most do by default.  when connected to a real network you get an `nxdomain` back quickly and it goes on its merry way. but with no access to dns server,, but having one configured, you have to wait for the query to timeout.